# PHP align text vertically with tabulators

Tags: php, alignment

This might be very noobish question and I'm sure someone already asked this but I didn't find anything. So my problem is pretty simple. In my php file I have function that saves visitor's IP address along with timestamp into file:

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$timestamp=date("\td.m.Y  H:i:s");
$fp = fopen('log', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $ip."  ".$timestamp."\n");
fclose($fp);
```

I use \t to put tabulator between IP and timestamp, but IPs are different lenght so it does this:

```
86.122.146.130          05.08.2017  09:59:25
188.175.16.157          05.08.2017  13:36:42
60.191.38.77    05.08.2017  17:37:44
106.74.48.171   05.08.2017  21:38:57
185.110.132.239         06.08.2017  02:08:04
```

How can I align timestamps vertically? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to pad with spaces and align the values:

```
$line = sprintf("%-20s %20s\n", $ip, $timestamp);
```

Code above returns a string with two fields of 20-character length, where first field is left-aligned (note the minus sign).

Also you can use [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function (by default it pads a string with spaces from right side):

```
$line = str_pad($ip, 20) . str_pad($timestamp, 20) . "\n";
```